# "first argument must be string or compiled pattern" error in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For the below code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('syslog.csv')
with open('data.json',encoding="utf8") as data_file:
  file_contents = data_file.read()
data = json.loads(file_contents)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(data['results'])

count = []

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        df3 = df2["sample_syslog_message"].str.match(row['Regex'])
        if df3.any() == True:
            count.append(index)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(index)
        break
```

It raises an exception "first argument must be string or compiled pattern". The pattern for which the loop is failing is "%PLATFORM-PWRMON-1-IDPROM_INVALID\s*:.*".

I tried checking this online on multiple regex platforms to check if the regex pattern is malformed,but all the platforms indicate that the regex is fine.

Any ideas why this testcase might be failing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just in case, what does `print(type(row['Regex']))` say?

Comment: For test cases without exception it says <class 'str'>, but for exception one it is <class 'float'>.

Comment: It is pretty clear then, no? A float is not a valid regex pattern (and needless to say, it is definitely not equal to `%PLATFORM-PWRMON-1-IDPROM_INVALID\s*:.*`).

Comment: Yes, I can understand that. But what I don't understand is why the code is treating a string regex pattern as a float?

Comment: As you have one regex per row, you need to loop here. You can't use `Series.str.match` which takes a single regex

Comment: It does not "treat a string regex pattern as a float". You don't have a string regex pattern. You have a float. I can't say more without seeing your JSON file contents.

Comment: @mozway: `row`, produced by `iterrows()`, is a string-indexed `Series`, and `row["Regex"]` is a scalar (as demonstrated by `type(row["Regex"])`), a single value (though, apparently, not a single _regex_).

Comment: Then OP should provide a reproducible example

Comment: @mozway Also note that this is a bad dupe: the regex is not in the same row, but in an entirely different dataframe. I agree on the reproducible example comment, which is why I said it is impossible to say more without knowing the contents of `data.json`. The trivial answer that we _can_ say is "your `data` is not what you think it is".

Comment: I can change the dupe link once OP updates the question (or reopen if needed)

Comment: If your data is not disclosable, then you're on your own. Your next task is to figure out why there is a float in a `Regex` field. Try to print the "bad" `row`, then use any identifying features to see which entries in the JSON file it corresponds to.

Comment: @Amadan A float might typically be a `NaN` ;)

Comment: @mozway Good point, as Python parses `NaN` as a number, in violation of [JSON standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-7). Still definitely not `"%PLATFORM-PWRMON-1-IDPROM_INVALID\s*:.*"` — have to see what is actually in the file. Also, `NaN` that would be so handled would need to be unquoted, whereas a string would have to be quoted — so there is not much chance one is being misparsed.

Comment: Rightly pointed out by you guys, the output for the row['Regex'] is printed as NaN. Will have to give a better look at the data to see why this is printed. Will update here on that.

Comment: Pandas seems to like using `NaN` as a placeholder for missing values, even in contexts where a non-numeric type would otherwise be expected. It seems likely that there is something irregular in the JSON.